# Open image set in ImageView into the Gallery on clicking on image

Tags: android, imageview, android-gallery

I have set an image in ImageView and have its uri and path.
Now I want when I click on that image in ImageView, It should pop up or get displayed in orignl size in gallery.

Every code available is for picking up image from gallery, but I want to view a known image in gallery.
Please help.

Comment: **gallery** or `galleryView` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set this code on clicklistner :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("filepath"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```